How do i load and plot this 1x1 timeseries mat file into python?
I've been trying to open the data and since it is nested I have not been able to extract the data.
The data is a simple time series of forward angle vs time.
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Wed Aug 28 13:06:06 2024',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'None': MatlabOpaque([(b'Fwd_Q', b'MCOS', b'timeseries', array([3707764736,          2,          1,          1,          1,
                               5], dtype=uint32))                                                                   ],
              dtype=[('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')]),
 '__function_workspace__': array([[ 0,  1, 73, ...,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=uint8)}

This is the output from just the data sample, the data is hidden inside the 'None' object.
I tried all kinds of solutions and it was not working, even read that the data type might not be compatible with python.
If i use scipy's loadmat, i am able to load the the file but I can't access the data.
I tried to convert the timeseries to a time table so that i can convert it to a txt format. I tried,
'''
data = load('Fwd_I.mat')
tt = timeseries2timetable(data.Fwd_I)
'''
But tt is just a 8x1 timetable whereas my data.Fwd_I has Time: 8x1 and Data:8x16,384.
How can I convert this to any readable format by python

MatlabOpaque means it's a mstlab construct that can't be converted to numpy. Can you save the mat as plain matrix?  cell and struct containing matrix are ok as well.
